# setkeycodes: ioctl KDSETKEYCODE: Invalid argument

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard, keyboard-event

I'm trying to map <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>Left-Arrow</kbd> to <kbd>Home</kbd>.

When I run `showkey --scancodes` (on console) and press <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>Left-Arrow</kbd>, I get:

```
0xe0 0x5b 0xe0 0x4b 0xe0 0xdb 0xe0 0xcb
```

`showkey` (also at console) tells me that <kbd>Home</kbd> has keycode 102.

So I try:

```
% sudo setkeycodes e05be04be0dbe0cb 102
setkeycodes: failed to set scancode ffff207f to keycode 102: ioctl KDSETKEYCODE: Invalid argument

% sudo setkeycodes e05be04b 102
setkeycodes: failed to set scancode e05b00cb to keycode 102: ioctl KDSETKEYCODE: Invalid argument

% sudo setkeycodes 5b4bdbcb 102
setkeycodes: failed to set scancode 5b4afc4b to keycode 102: ioctl KDSETKEYCODE: Invalid argument

% sudo setkeycodes 5b4b 102
setkeycodes: failed to set scancode 5b4b to keycode 102: ioctl KDSETKEYCODE: Invalid argument
```

My keyboard is the chassis built-in one on my laptop. It's not listed by `lsusb`.

How do I map <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>Left-Arrow</kbd> to <kbd>Home</kbd> with `setkeycodes`?